# Create new text file with echo only

Tags: files, echo

I have a repertory called 'data' and have multiple random files in it.
I want to create a 'results.txt' file with all the names of the files in 'data'.

I want to use only the command echo in one command. So far I've done:

```
cd data
```

and then

```
echo * > ../results.txt
```

It does work but not in the same command.

Comment: Why? what is special about "one command"? what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you could avoid the `cd` by doing

```
echo data/* > results.txt
```

however this will result in the filenames in `results.txt` being prepended with the pathname `data/`.

In `zsh`, you could use the `:t` (**t**ail) modifier to strip off the pathname:

```
echo data/*(:t) > results.txt            # zsh only
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Not using echo command which you mentioned but does the same thing..

ls -1a >../result.txt

Answer (score 0):

No need to cd. You can do

```
ls data > results.txt
```

Don't put a `*` because that will cause all results to start with `data/`. However my answer did not use the `echo` command as you needed.